# Ubuntu server 12.04/12.10 not getting past "Select a language"

Tags: installation, server

I am trying to install ubuntu server on my pc , i have burned the ISO to an Cd and tried to burn it on a usb, in both cases it hangs at "Select a language"  i cannot move nor select anything.

I have try several things but I do not know how to get past this, could anyone please help?

Kind regards.

Comment: I have the same problem. I started suspecting that there's something wrong with my bios settings, but I have no idea what exactly. Any clues will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the alt installer.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Also Have you check the MD5 of the disk to make sure it has downloaded properly?

Comment: The Alternate CD doesn't exist for 12.10 any more.